# Using JQ and regex to extract just matching regex string

Tags: regex, jq

I have the following input json which I obtain from a curl command and I'm feeding it to jq.

```
{
  "version": "14.10.0-ee",
  "revision": "ad109bc62af"
}
```

I'm trying to use jq to extract just '14.10.0'.

I have the following jq command but it's just returning "14.10.0-ee"

```
jq '. | select(.version|capture("^[0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,}")).version'
```

I've looked at the jq documentation [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE) and I'm not able to figure the correct syntax.
I've tried scan, capture, and match without success.

I am able to achieve what I want if I pipe the result to grep but I would prefer to do it all in one command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @VictorBarros - Since you've had success with grep, it would be helpful if you gave more details.

Comment: @peak - Here is the grep I'm piping the output to.
`grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}'`

Answer (score 2):

Yet you can use **capture** through **`[[:digit:].]+`** pattern

```
jq -r '.version| capture("(?<v>[[:digit:].]+)").v'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4RzWDxKxqL)</kbd>

Comment: `.|` is redundant, it can be removed: `jq '.version|capture("...").v'`

Comment: Hi @BarbarosÖzhan .  Thank you so much.  That did the trick.  I was not using the `[[:digit:].]+`

Answer (score 1):

```
.version|scan("^[^-]+")
```

or

```
.version|scan("^[0-9.]+")
```

Don't overcomplicate it ;)

Call jq with flag `-r` for *raw output*, that is without quotation marks around strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can split on the hyphen and then take the first element:

```
.version|split("-")|first
```

or

```
.version/"-"|first
```

(`/` on strings is equivalent to calling split)

Call jq with flag `-r` for *raw output*, that is without quotation marks around strings.